# Return Blank Value instead of '?'

Tags: sql, odbc, teradata

The query I am working on is pulling PO numbers. In some cases the PO numbers were converted from a legacy system. I am trying to list both the new/converted PO number as well as the legacy PO number. In cases where there is no legacy PO number the query is returning '?' instead of blank.

I have been searching for a way for it just to return as a blank, but have not had any luck. I added the following to the query, but it has not been successful:

```
REPLACE (PO_PO.PO_NUMBER,',','') AS PO_NUMBER,
        (CASE 
            WHEN PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR IS NULL THEN ''
            WHEN PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR = '?' THEN ''
            ELSE PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR
         END) AS LEGACY_PO_NUMBER
```

An example Which returns this:

| PO_NUMBER | LEGACY_PO_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 8173063 | ? |
| 8167171 | MF76991001 |

Comment: What's your client? E.g. both Teradata's BTEQ as well as SQL Assistant will display NULLs as question mark by default (which can be changed). What is returned by `char2hexint(PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR)` for those rows?

Answer (score 0):

The string might look like `'?'` but it isn't.  Maybe there are trailing spaces.  Or invisible characters.  You might find that a regular expression is more helpful:

```
(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR, '^[0-9A-Z]+$'
      THEN PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR
      ELSE ''
 END)
```

Comment: @Grodon Linoff I input: (CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR, '^[0-9A-Z]+$') THEN IS NULL
THEN PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR
ELSE ''
END) AS LEGACY_PO_NUMBER and it gave the "ORA-00936: missing expression" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison to the question mark can create an issue here. Can you try the following and share the output here?

```
REPLACE (PO_PO.PO_NUMBER,',','') AS PO_NUMBER,
    (CASE 
        WHEN PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR IS NULL THEN ''
        WHEN replace(trim(PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR), '?', 'question_mark') = 'question_mark' THEN ''
        ELSE PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR
     END) AS LEGACY_PO_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it gave the same result.

Comment: Can I have the actual value in this field for the particular PO number?

Comment: For PO number 8173063,  the Legacy PO Number field is blank, but it outputs ? </br> When I copy the cell, it just shows ? (no spaces or other characters)

Comment: is </br> actually represent any special character or it is just there? you can try to use trim(trailing '</br>' from PO_PO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NBR) and then compare the question mark sign with the rest. As it is legacy data I can't recreate the same locally.

Comment: The </br> was meant to add a line break in the comment and is not in the query! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Since the above query is not working as you said, I have an alternative. You can use the length of the column to eliminate any unwanted value. For example, if length is less than 2 than it is not a valid legacy PO number

Answer (score 0):

@dnoeth answered this correctly in a comment. I am using SQL Assistant and Null fields were set to display as ?.

I changed this by going to Tools > Options > Data Format, then cleared the "Display this string for Null data values" text field. Values now show as blanks.

Comment: Since Terada distinguish `NULL` and empty string (`''`) now you will not be able to distinguish them in the output (and `NULL` cannot be compared to anything with `=`). My preferred setting for this regardless of the DBMS is a `NULL` or `<NULL>`. Question mark is not so useful because it may be produced by invalid codepage